# Using Named Ranges as Variables in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am putting together a pricing calculator for work in Google Sheets, I've coded a few functions in JS. They work fine.

The issue I am having, is that I want someone less code orientated to change certain variables.

I had an idea of using Named Ranges with all the 'Settings' on a separate Spreadsheet. Getting these cells and values and converting them into variables in JS using a function.

I've managed to get the Named Ranges, and also the values into JS. (`getValues()` and `getNamedRanges()`) But I am having trouble generating the variables from them. I think this is called dynamically generated variables? I've tried using eval() (Which is apparently not a great idea i've read) But I can't get that working either.

Would I need to define all the variables I am using instead of generating them based on what the Named Ranges and their values are?

I am relatively new to JS, so I am not sure if I am missing something obvious!

```
function convertNamedRangeToVariables() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sa = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  function getValuesOfNamedRange(x) {
  return ss.getRangeByName(x).getValues();
  }

  var namedRanges = sa.getNamedRanges();

  for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {

    var name = namedRanges[i].getName();
    var value = getValuesOfNamedRange(name);
    Logger.log(name);
    Logger.log(value);
    eval('var' + name + '=' + value); 

  }

  return
}
```

Comment: You'd be best to post some of your code in your question to get the ball rolling...

Comment: Thanks Lee, I've added some code.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code *might* have worked but the variables you are creating would only be around inside the `convertNamedRangeToVariables` function.

Personally, I would create an object for the data (outside the function) to keep it global:

```js
var data = {};

function convertNamedRangeToVariables() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sa = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  function getValuesOfNamedRange(x) 
  {
    return ss.getRangeByName(x).getValues();
  }

  var namedRanges = sa.getNamedRanges();

  for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) 
  {
    var name = namedRanges[i].getName();
    var value = getValuesOfNamedRange(name);
    data[name] = value;
  }
}
```

Once you have called your `convertNamedRangeToVariables` function you can then refer to your data:

`console.log( data["aNamedRange"] );`